# Trying to install proclipsing into eclipse

Tags: eclipse

So i am trying to install proclipsing into eclipse but the link wont work
the link I am using Is http://proclipsing.googlecode.com/svn/tags/current_releases/proclipsingSite/
and the error eclipse gives me is:
could not find http://proclipsing.googlecode.com/svn/tags/current_releases/proclipsingSite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Code has been closed in 2015/2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Developers#Google_Code) and the projects were archived: see [archive of *proclipsing*](https://code.google.com/archive/p/proclipsing/). Therefore the update site does not work anymore.

*Proclipsing* was migrated to GitHub. See the [**installation instructions**](https://github.com/ybakos/proclipsing#installing) there.